# Testcontainers could not be instantiated on GoCD

Tags: java, docker, testcontainers, go-cd

I'm trying to run AWS DynamoDB with Testcontainers and spring-boot for tests. It runs and executes tests successfully on my MAC with Docker engine 19.03.13 and higher, Java 15. Unfortunately it fails when trying to run on GoCD. Below is the details.

Gradle:

```
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.3'
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.15.3
```

'

Java/Spring:

```
@Testcontainers
@TestInstance(PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest()
public class DynamodbTestContainer {
    protected AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB;
    protected ApplicationInfoRepo applicationInfoRepo;

    @Container
    static final GenericContainer dynamoDb = new GenericContainer("amazon/dynamodb-local:1.16.0")
            .withCommand("-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory -sharedDb")
            .withExposedPorts(8000);

    @BeforeAll
    public void init() {
        var endpointUrl = String.format("http://localhost:%d", dynamoDb.getFirstMappedPort());

amazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()              .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(endpointUrl, "eu-west-2"))
                .build();
```

Error Cause:

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Unsupported protocol scheme found: 'localhost:2376
```

Whole exception stack:

```
ApplicationInfoRepoTest > initializationError FAILED
    java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy: Provider org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy could not be instantiated
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:584)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:806)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:724)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1396)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:134)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:178)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.authConfig(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:310)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:242)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:229)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$1(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:89)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:53)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$beforeAll$2(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.beforeAll(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:192)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

        Caused by:
        com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Unsupported protocol scheme found: 'localhost:2376
            at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultDockerClientConfig.checkDockerHostScheme(DefaultDockerClientConfig.java:107)
            at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultDockerClientConfig.<init>(DefaultDockerClientConfig.java:90)
            at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultDockerClientConfig$Builder.build(DefaultDockerClientConfig.java:438)
            at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy.<init>(EnvironmentAndSystemPropertyClientProviderStrategy.java:18)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
            at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:782)
            ... 81 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The GoCD environment was incorrectly configured, as DOCKER_HOST was set to "localhost:2376". After changing the DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2376 it worked as excepted.